# Simple Multithreaded Web Server in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, webserver

I'm trying to write a really simple web server with Python that is multithreaded. Right now the code looks like this

```
from socket import *
import threading
import time

class serverThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, serverPort):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.serverPort = serverPort
        self.serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connectionThreads = []
    def run(self):
        self.serverSocket.bind(('', self.serverPort))
        self.serverSocket.listen(1)
        while True:
            #Establish the connection
            print 'Ready to serve...'
            connectionSocket = self.serverSocket.accept()
            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024) #Get message
            print "Message recieved, opening new thread"
            self.connectionThreads.append(connectionThread())
            self.connectionThreads[len(connectionThreads)-1].start()
    def close(self):
        for t in self.connectionThreads:
            t.close()
        self.serverSocket.close()

class connectionThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connSocket, message):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connSocket = connSocket
        self.message = message
    def run(self):
        try:
            filename = self.message.split()[1] #Getting requested HTML page
            f = open(filename[1:]) #Opening data stream from HTML
            outputdata = f.read() #Reading HTML page
            f.close() #Closing data stream from HTML
            self.connSocket.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n") #Send one HTTP header line into socket
            for i in range(0, len(outputdata)): #Send the content of the requested file to the client
                self.connSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        except IOError: #Triggered if user requests bad link
            self.connSocket.send("404 Not Found") #Send response message for file not found
        finally:
            self.connSocket.close()

def main():
    server = serverThread(8031)
    server.start()
    end = raw_input("Press enter to stop server...")
    server.close()
    print "Program complete"

main()
```

My strategy is to start the web server in the main method and then start connection threads from the server thread. I have a simple helloworld html file in the same directory which I'm using to test it from localhost

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    HELLO WORLD!
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I go to type localhost:8031/hello.html in Chrome, it just loads forever saying "waiting for localhost". I have a print that is supposed to happen whenever a new message is received but it's not printing which tells me the server is not receiving messages properly

When I try to connect a second time Chrome flat out tells me the connection was refused and when I press enter to stop the server it seems to quit fine but then I get an error message

[image]

I'm frustrated and not sure how to debug this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors in your code that I went through in the posted code below. General notes are:

- use SO_REUSEADDR on the server so you don't have to wait to execute a second time
- shutdown a socket before close or the underlying socket may stay open, hanging your browser
- you close client sockets in two places... catch errors so that you can close them all
- that 'Bad file descriptor' error is a good thing. It happened because you closed the socket and it lets your server thread know its time to terminate. You could catch it an exit gracefully if you want
- you need a better way to deal with background threads. Right now your list just grows forever and over time most will be stale. I marked them as daemon threads so that the program would terminate at the end, but you need something else.

Fixing up the errors I came up with

```
from socket import *
import threading
import time

class serverThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, serverPort):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.serverPort = serverPort
        self.serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.connectionThreads = []
    def run(self):
        self.serverSocket.bind(('', self.serverPort))
        self.serverSocket.listen(1)
        while True:
            #Establish the connection
            print 'Ready to serve...'
            connectionSocket,addr = self.serverSocket.accept()
            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024) #Get message
            print "Message recieved, opening new thread"
            self.connectionThreads.append(connectionThread(connectionSocket, message))
            self.connectionThreads[-1].daemon = 1
            self.connectionThreads[-1].start()
    def close(self):
        for t in self.connectionThreads:
            try:
                t.connSocket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
                t.connSocket.close()
            except socket.error:
                pass
        self.serverSocket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
        self.serverSocket.close()

class connectionThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, connSocket, message):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connSocket = connSocket
        self.message = message
    def run(self):
        try:
            filename = self.message.split()[1] #Getting requested HTML page
            f = open(filename[1:]) #Opening data stream from HTML
            outputdata = f.read() #Reading HTML page
            f.close() #Closing data stream from HTML
            self.connSocket.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n") #Send one HTTP header line into socket
            for i in range(0, len(outputdata)): #Send the content of the requested file to the client
                self.connSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        except IOError: #Triggered if user requests bad link
            self.connSocket.send("404 Not Found") #Send response message for file not found
        finally:
            self.connSocket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
            self.connSocket.close()

def main():
    server = serverThread(8031)
    server.daemon = 1
    server.start()
    end = raw_input("Press enter to stop server...")
    server.close()
    print "Program complete"

main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely appreciate all your help

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are trying to access a file or socket you already closed.

See line:

```
sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
```

You are trying to accept a request with a socket that you already closed.

Check the file descriptor(could be a socket) that is usually represented as a number.